# How to color a Mandelbrot?

Tags: c++, sfml

After following this very simple tutorial that gives you all the code (http://warp.povusers.org/Mandelbrot/) I am not having any luck on figuring out how to color the outline like in the pictures.

> > If in our example we map n to a color so that from 0 to MaxIterations/2-1 the color goes from black to red and from MaxIterations/2 to MaxIterations-1 the color goes from red to white, we get the following image:

```
void compute_mandelbrot(double left, double right, double top, double bottom, double start, double end) //improved mandelbort following a tutorial
{
    double ImageHeight = 960;
    double ImageWidth = 960;

    //double MinRe = -2.5;
    //double MaxRe = 1.25;
    //double MinIm = -1.2;
    double MinRe = left;
    double MaxRe = right;
    double MinIm = top;
    double MaxIm = MinIm + (MaxRe - MinRe)*ImageHeight / ImageWidth;
    double Re_factor = (MaxRe - MinRe) / (ImageWidth - 1);
    double Im_factor = (MaxIm - MinIm) / (ImageHeight - 1);
    //unsigned MAX_ITERATIONS = 100;

    /*int r = 0x00, g = 0x00, b = 0x00;*/


    for (unsigned y = 0; y<ImageHeight; ++y)
    {
        double c_im = MaxIm - y*Im_factor;
        for (unsigned x = 0; x<ImageWidth; ++x)
        {
            //vertex.color = sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
            //r = g = b = 0;

            double c_re = MinRe + x*Re_factor;

            double Z_re = c_re, Z_im = c_im;
            bool isInside = true;
            for (unsigned n = 0; n<MAX_ITERATIONS; ++n)
            {
                //vertex.color = sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255); //figure is black
                //vertex.color = sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255); //figure is white
                r = g = b = 0;

                double Z_re2 = Z_re*Z_re, Z_im2 = Z_im*Z_im;
                if (Z_re2 + Z_im2 > 4)
                {

                    isInside = false;

                    auto half = MAX_ITERATIONS / 2.0;

                    if (n < half) {
                        r = n / half * 255;
                    }
                    else {
                        r = 255;
                        g = b = (n - half) / half * 255;
                    }

                    vertex.color = sf::Color(r, g, b, 255);

                    break;
                }

                Z_im = 2 * Z_re*Z_im + c_im;
                Z_re = Z_re2 - Z_im2 + c_re;


            }

            if (isInside)
            {
                //vertex.color = sf::Color(r, g, b, 255); //line pattern

                mutex.lock();
                vertex.position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
                varray.append(vertex);
                mutex.unlock();
            } 
        }
    }



}
```

I don't think I understand what I'm meant to do there, I tried a few things including what's in the code but with no luck.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/244864 if you want your question deleted. By posting here, you've given the site a license to distribute the content under a [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) license. Blanking the question is considered vandalism, even when the post is yours, and will be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

At the line `isInside = false;` you have a value of `n` at which the point escapes the set. Use this value of `n` to set the r,g,b values for the point based on your colour preferences. If the point does not escape it will be black (or whatever you initialise r,g and b to).

> map n to a color so that from 0 to MaxIterations/2-1 the color goes from black to red and from MaxIterations/2 to MaxIterations-1 the color goes from red to white

This is simple RGB math, e.g.

```
auto half = MaxIterations/2.0;

if( n < half ) {
  r = n / half;
}else {
  r = 1.0;
  g = b = (n - half) / half;
}
```

which gives rgb in the range 0-1, multiply by 255 if you're using integers for colours

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pete, I may have misunderstood your already simple instructions, I implemented your code in the same if statement as IsInside = false; multiplied r,g,b *255 but this is the result I got https://i.imgur.com/uN99b8A.png

Comment: @reversecodingguru you have inverted the logic - set r,g,b in the block immediately after isInside = false before break. Also reset r,g,b to zero at the start of each loop.

Comment: I'm afraid the issue is still there, [here's the code in picture format if you can spot my mistake (link)](https://i.imgur.com/74EOSjT.png)

Comment: @reversecodingguru nope, you have to do some work yourself. That code isn't ever setting pixel colours, and isn't painting the points the points you want coloured red.